# Scala fat jar dependency issue while Job submit

Tags: scala, sbt, spark-streaming

I have written simple kafka stream using Scala. It is working good in local. I have taken fat jar and submitted in scala cluster. I am getting class not found error after submit the job. if I extract the fat jar, it has all dependency inside the fat jar.

why I am getting class not found error ?. How to solve this ?

**Note:** if I deploy(copy) the fat jar into Spark/jars folder manually. I don't see any issue. But, it is not correct approach

I am using window 7 & running master and worker node on the same machine.

**JOB Submit**

```
spark-2.2\bin>spark-submit --class Welcome --master spark://169.254.208.125:7077 C:\Gnana\cass-conn-assembly-0.1.jar
```

**Code**

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Milliseconds, Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._


object Welcome {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("demo").setMaster("spark://169.254.208.125:7077");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.1.2")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Milliseconds(100))
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "192.168.1.2:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )
    val topics = Array("test")
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )
    val lines = messages.map(_.value)
    lines.map(li=>{val arr= li.split(",");(arr(0).toInt,arr(1),arr(2),arr(3))}).saveToCassandra("inventory", "emp",SomeColumns("emp_id","create_date","emp_city","emp_name"))
    println(" Spark is ready !!!!!! ");

    /*sys.ShutdownHookThread {
      println("Gracefully stopping Spark Streaming Application")
      ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)
      println("Application stopped")
    }*/

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
  }
  def sayHello(msg:String): Unit = {
    print("welcome to Sacala "+msg);
  }
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
organization := "com.demo"
name := "cass-conn"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
val connectorVersion = "2.0.7"
val kafka_stream_version = "1.6.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion  % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion  % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion  % "provided",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % connectorVersion  ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" %  "2.2.0"  % "provided",
)

mergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x => (mergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```

**Error 1:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies$.Subscribe(ConsumerStrategy.scala:256)
        at Welcome$.main(Welcome.scala:32)
        at Welcome.main(Welcome.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.sca
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 12 more
```

**Build Log**

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to C:\Gnana\cass-conn\target\scala-2.11\classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Including: slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
[info] Including: joda-time-2.3.jar
[info] Including: kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.jar
[info] Including: scala-library-2.11.8.jar
[info] Including: jopt-simple-4.9.jar
[info] Including: metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
[info] Including: slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar
[info] Including: log4j-1.2.17.jar
[info] Including: joda-convert-1.2.jar
[info] Including: zkclient-0.9.jar
[info] Including: scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar
[info] Including: zookeeper-3.4.8.jar
[info] Including: jline-0.9.94.jar
[info] Including: netty-3.7.0.Final.jar
[info] Including: lz4-1.3.0.jar
[info] Including: scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar
[info] Including: snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar
[info] Including: kafka-clients-0.10.1.0.jar
[info] Including: spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar
[info] Including: spark-tags_2.11-2.2.0.jar
[info] Including: unused-1.0.0.jar
[info] Including: netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar
[info] Including: commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
[info] Including: jsr166e-1.1.0.jar
[info] Including: spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.7.jar
[info] Including: commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'NOTICE' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\NOTICE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\NOTICE' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'org\xerial\snappy\native\README' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\LICENSE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\license' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'LICENSE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\LICENSE' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'LICENSE' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\DEPENDENCIES' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\INDEX.LIST' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.datastax.cassandra\cassandra-driver-core\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.datastax.cassandra\cassandra-driver-core\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.datastax.cassandra\cassandra-driver-mapping\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.datastax.cassandra\cassandra-driver-mapping\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jffi\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jffi\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-constants\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-constants\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-ffi\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-ffi\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-posix\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-posix\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-x86asm\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.github.jnr\jnr-x86asm\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.google.guava\guava\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.google.guava\guava\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.twitter\jsr166e\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.twitter\jsr166e\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.yammer.metrics\metrics-core\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\com.yammer.metrics\metrics-core\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\commons-collections\commons-collections\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\commons-collections\commons-collections\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\io.netty\netty-all\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\io.netty\netty-all\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\io.netty\netty\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\io.netty\netty\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\jline\jline\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\jline\jline\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\joda-time\joda-time\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\joda-time\joda-time\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\log4j\log4j\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\log4j\log4j\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\net.sf.jopt-simple\jopt-simple\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\net.sf.jopt-simple\jopt-simple\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.apache.spark\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.apache.spark\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.apache.spark\spark-tags_2.11\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.apache.spark\spark-tags_2.11\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.joda\joda-convert\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.joda\joda-convert\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.spark-project.spark\unused\pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\maven\org.spark-project.spark\unused\pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'org\apache\spark\unused\UnusedStubClass.class' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to 51 files
[warn] Strategy 'first' was applied to a file
[warn] Strategy 'rename' was applied to 9 files
[info] SHA-1: 85f8513511b46290883ab70f2525b04a8d3c33d7
```

Comment: Can you see this class in your fat jar?

Comment: yes, I am able to see this class in my fat jar.   target\scala-2.11\cass-conn-assembly-0.1.jar\org\apache\kafka\clients\consumer\Consumer.class

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html Can you please try once use spark kafka streaming 0.8

Comment: I am using Kafka 2.12 and Spark 2.2. so I chose 0-10. it works good in local. is any reason do I need to try with 0.8

Comment: problem related to class not found not related to version, I think. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yess you are right i just want to check version compatibility because if that class is not compatible with the version then also give you class not found error, what version kafka broker you are using?

Comment: I am using kafka 2.12. I will check and update you on this.

Comment: Since I am new, I don't have idea to convert my code to 0.8 api. I added my source code. could u please help m eon this ?

Comment: @Gnana you do not need to use 0.8, see my answer below.

Comment: @soote I am facing the same problem even after adding the kafka in build.sbt. Please take a look at my build log

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your spark-streaming-kafka dependency to

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % "2.2.0"
```

build a fresh fat jar and see if this solves the problem.

final build.sbt looks like

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion  % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion  % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion  % "provided",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % connectorVersion  ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" %  "2.2.0"
)
```

Comment: I am getting error in my code if I use 0-8 version, since code is developed using 0-11. . I have added build log in my question. can u please look at my build log and give me any suggestions

Comment: version is not a problem. if I deploy fat jar  in spark/jar folder. it is working good. but it is not correct approach. please check and help me on this

Comment: Can you please explain, why making spark-streaming dependency provided can be a bad idea?

Comment: You would need spark streaming classes at runtime right? But it may not be a bad idea because perhaps your Hadoop distribution will provide those binaries so you don't need to package them in your own jar.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the kafka dependency:

```
"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.1.0"
```

Add that an you will be all good.

I have my `build.sbt` setup like this:

```
"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka"                      % "0.10.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming"            % "2.2.0" % "provided"
```

Comment: I added "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.1.0". But no luck. I have added build log in my question. can u please look at my build log and give me any suggestions

Comment: yes. I am getting same error. Please take a look at my build log