# Spark Parallel Stream - object not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Spark's multiple inputstream reader to read message from Kafka. I am getting below mentioned error. If I don't use multiple input stream reader , I am not getting any error. To achieve performance, I need to use parallel concept, testing purpose I using only one.

**Error**

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = test, partition = 0, offset = 120, CreateTime = -1, checksum = 2372777361, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 48, key = null, value = 10051,2018-03-15 17:12:24+0000,Bentonville,Gnana))
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeValue(Serializer.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/03/15 17:12:24 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0 in stage 470.0 (TID 470) had a not serializable result: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
```

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.Success
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Milliseconds, StreamingContext}

object ParallelStreamJob {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkHelper.getOrCreateSparkSession()
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Milliseconds(50))
    val kafkaStream = {

      val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
        "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
        "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
        "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
        "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
      )

      val topics = Array("test")
      val numPartitionsOfInputTopic = 1
      val streams = (1 to numPartitionsOfInputTopic) map { _ =>
        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
          ssc,
          PreferConsistent,
          Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
        )
      }
      val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams)
      val sparkProcessingParallelism = 1 
      unifiedStream.repartition(sparkProcessingParallelism)
    }

    kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd=> {
      rdd.foreach(conRec=> {
        println(conRec.value())
      })
    })

    println(" Spark parallel reader is ready !!!")

   ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

**sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
val connectorVersion = "2.0.7"
val kafka_stream_version = "1.6.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion  ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion  ,
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % connectorVersion  ,
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" %  sparkVersion  ,
)
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is clear `java.io.NotSerializableException:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord`. The [ConsumerRecord](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html) class doesn't extend `Serializable`

Try to take out `value` field of `ConsumerRecord` before `foreachRdd` operation `kafkaStream.map(_.value())`.

Update 1: The above fix doesn't work because exception happen at `ssc.union(streams)`.`ssc.union(streams)` requires data transfer between nodes, it must serialize data. So, you can take out `value` field by `map` before `union` operation to fix the issue.

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParam) ).map(_.value())
```

Comment: val cusRecord = kafkaStream.map(_.value())
    cusRecord.foreachRDD(rdd=> {
      rdd.foreach(conRec=> {
        println(conRec)
      })
    })
please correct my code. same issue after using map.

Comment: Sorry, pls try this one `val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams.map(_.value))`. If it works, I will update my answer.

Comment: compilation error Error:(37, 51) value value is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]]
      val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams.map(_.value))

Comment: Error:(29, 60) missing parameter type
      val streams = (1 to numPartitionsOfInputTopic) map { _ => KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams) ) }.map(_.map(_.value))

Comment: Sorry about my careless responses. This one would work :)
`KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
            ssc,
            null,
            Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParam)
          ).map(_.value())
val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams) ...`

Comment: sorry getting error while running my code. 18/03/15 22:02:02 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1521169321850 ms
scala.MatchError: null
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.getPreferredHosts(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:103) :(

Comment: Could u please try with my code and give me solution ? thanks in advance

Comment: additional error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: This consumer has already been closed.

Comment: Thanks, I have added PreferConsistent instead of null( ssc, null ) . it works good. please add these change I will accept and it will useful for others

Comment: Ohh, sorry. I use `null` at that because my laziness of typing

Comment: could u please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228397/scala-fat-jar-dependency-issue-while-job-submit

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have 1 topic then you shouldn't use creating multiple Kafkastreams as you are using the direct approach which will automatically create as many numbers of threads as there are a number of Kafka partitions for a topic.Spark will automatically take care of parallelizing your tasks if you follow DirectApproach.
Try to use repartition() at RDD level instead repartitioning the Dstream itself.